# Giving errors while running "ng serve"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

The angular project name is "PaymentApp". After "ng serve" it starts running but giving lots of errors.
It's showing "Cannot GET /" instead of the default angular template.

Please refer to the attached images :
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: chrome tab]

Comment: I think the angularjs tag is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing spaces from your directory name. I've had issues in the past with this.